# Javascript array access

Tags: javascript

How do i the use document.write() in javascript to access this form of array?

```
({"1":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":1},
  "2":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":2},
  "3":{"1":1,"2":2,"3":1},
  "4":{"1":1,"2":2,"3":2},
  "5":{"1":2,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1},
  "6":{"1":2,"2":1,"3":1,"4":2},
  "7":{"1":2,"2":1,"3":2},
  "8":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":1},
  "9":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2}})
```

Comment: You can't. `document.write` gets passed a string, it has no functionality for accessing data structures. (You have to address the strings in the data structure as normal and then hand the result to `write`).

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Programming_-_the_real_basics#Objects

Comment: This is not an array. It's an object with numeric keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if you want to access the first element of the first array, you should write:

```
theData=({"1":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":1},
  "2":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":2},
  "3":{"1":1,"2":2,"3":1},
  "4":{"1":1,"2":2,"3":2},
  "5":{"1":2,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1},
  "6":{"1":2,"2":1,"3":1,"4":2},
  "7":{"1":2,"2":1,"3":2},
  "8":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":1},
  "9":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2}});
document.write(theData[1][1]); //1
```

Since you apparently use jQuery, here is how to print your elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $.getJSON('array.php?callback=?', function(data) {
     if(data) {
         $.each(data,function(key,val){
              $.each(val,function(subkey,subval){
                  document.write(subval+" ");
              });
              document.write('<br/>');
         });
     } 
     else { alert('error'); } 
   });
```

});

Comment: `{}` does not give you an array, I recommend against misleading variable names

Comment: Your code gives error. "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BhhJU/)

Comment: i am using getjson to access the array, 
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON('array.php?callback=?', function(data) {  
     if(data) {
     
     document.write(data[0][0]);
     
     }
     else {
     alert('error');
     }
    });
   }); 
but i cant get it

Comment: It's still not an array. It's a numerically indexed object.

Comment: @jc_tan Made a jquery example

Comment: i have a question, how can i save the result in javascript array ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to a variable and use the bracket notation to access object properties.

```
var mydata = ({...});

mydata['1']['3'] //1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an array, but object of objects. So iterate over every object and check if there is a nested one. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8skH/1/) ***Side note: show some efforts, and better yet, try to search a little more, google is your best friend.***

```
function traverse ( data )
{
    for ( var index in data )
    {
        if ( typeof data[index] === "object" )
        {
            traverse ( data[index] );
        } else {
            document.write ( data[index] );
        }
    }
    document.write ( "<br/>" );
}

traverse ( a );
```